# jquery selector suggestor

Tags: jquery

We all know that there are many different selector combinations one can use to create a unique wrapped set of jQuery elements.

Does a tool (plugin, extension, etc) exist that allows the user to visually click on any section of the DOM (similar to Firebug's inspect feature) and auto-suggests relevant potential selectors that match that element?

The tool would have internal knowledge of jQuery selectors (CSS selectors fall short) and would take into account the surrounding elements + the DOM to provide 10-20 helpful selector suggestions.

Comment: Why not just look at the DOM and go "Oh I need this selector". It takes 30 seconds. It would also be a waste to use jQuery selectors, just use CSS3 selectors since that doesn't hardwire the jQuery dependency

Comment: some selectors are better than others. when building complex applications using selector1 might bring trouble down the road whereas selector2 is more robust and wont require modifications. It would be nice to have a simple list to choose from, especially for people new to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start point to play around with what you need (i hope) or just to understand:

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Htgtg/)

```
$("body").click(function(event) { // if you are not interested on 'body' himself use: $("body>*")

    // QUESTIONS:
    var Q_qwer = 'Not a parent';
    var Q_children = 'Not a children';
    var Q_last = 'Not last';
    var Q_first = 'Not first';

    //#

    if ($(event.target).children().size() > 0) {
        myChildren = $(event.target).children();
        var Q_parent = myChildren[0].nodeName + ' (ID: ' + myChildren[0].id + ' || CLASS: ' + myChildren[0].className + ' )';
    }
    if ($(event.target).parent().size() > 0) {
        myParent = $(event.target).parent();
        var Q_children = myParent[0].nodeName + ' (ID: ' + myParent[0].id + ' || CLASS: ' + myParent[0].className + ' )';     
    }
    if ($(event.target).is(':last-child')) {
        Q_last = 'LAST!' ;      
    }
    if ($(event.target).is(':first-child')) { // or use: $(event.target).index() == 0
        Q_first = 'FIRST!' ;     
    }

    $("#log").html(' event.target: ' + event.target +
                   ' <br> nodeName: ' + event.target.nodeName +
                   ' , Tag: ' + event.target.tagName +
                   ' <br> ID: ' + event.target.id +
                   ' <br> Class: ' + event.target.className +
                   ' <br> Href: ' + event.target.href +
                   ' <br> Value: ' + event.target.value +
                   ' <br> Children of: ' + Q_children +
                   ' <br> Parent of: ' + Q_parent + ' (First children)' +
                   ' <br> Last children?: ' + Q_last +
                   ' <br> First children?: ' + Q_first +
                   ' <br> .index( ' + $(event.target).index() + ')' +
                   ' <br> .eq( ' + $(event.target).prevAll().length + ')' +
                   ' <br> <hr>' + $(event.target).html()

                  );
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting approach, I was thinking more along the lines of a tool that has internal knowledge of jQuery selectors and could suggest among other alternatives $("table tr:last-child") for the last row in a table. (for example) Obviously this is a simple one, but if the tool was capable of offering 10-20 'smart' selectors taking into account it's surrounding elements, the DOM etc...could be very helpful.

Comment: @Jordan : I reedited a bit my codes. (this will help me too on one of my future CMS projects i think. ;)

Comment: @Raynos - Hi mate, I suppose that was a bad comment. Or?  (I needed something similar too for a future project so I was very interested on this Q. Please Don't take it bad.)

Comment: @roXon your UI for showing selector details is ugly and doesn't give me an easy copy & pastable unique selector for an element.

Comment: @Raynos - I appretiate your comment. It's the uglyest code on the web , I agree, but it can help after a second look on how to use the ev.target and get the most of it. ( using .get() is also possible.) Have you a better and neater suggestion?

Comment: @Raynos - Sorry I understand now your 2nd comment, yes, I agree, I was stilll stuck on getting something like: 'jQuery, tell me what is by your library exactly this element that I have clicked on?'

Comment: At least the Q. is still open, starred by me too, and I'm waiting to see more suggestions! :)

Comment: Well... it looks like such a tool may not exist. Maybe it would be a nice little project for some folks? ;) meanwhile, @roXon takes the cake for effort. Cheers dudes.

Comment: Right! looks like a possible nice little project! Thanks & good luck

Answer (score 1):

You could try this bookmarklet called [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/)

Comment: Interesting, doesn't really accomplish any more than firebug et all though. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I see... so I messed around with @roXon's attempt and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Htgtg/1/ It's not perfect, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

There is something in the Chrome developer tools that does this. Not fool proof but might be worth a try. If you inspect your Element in the dev tools, in the right panel in the elmements tab (CSS styles) there is a little cog, click it and click "New Style Rule", this adds a new CSS style rule in the style panel with a selector matching your element.

Comment: definitely not fool proof. I just inspected a last table row... The unknown tool I'm inquiring would provide something like $("table tr:last-child") as well as other relevant selectors. Whereas, Chrome only offered to fill out css for a simple tr. Thanks for the suggestion but misses the mark. Anybody know of any other solutions?

Comment: Oh well,  I'll +1 your question since I know no good alternative and it would be a nice feature to have. This is a relative new feature to the Chrome dev tools though, so I wouldn't be surprised if they make it a lot better in the next months or so.